# How to return multiple records from multiple tables bu a single stored procedure having parameters?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Suppose my stored procedure is:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'sp_QB_descriptionwise_select')
    BEGIN
        DROP  Procedure  sp_QB_descriptionwise_select
    END
GO
CREATE Procedure sp_QB_descriptionwise_select
    (
        @description nvarchar(max)
    )
AS

declare @type int
SELECT     Question.questionid, Question.question, Question.answer, Question.typeOfQuestion, QuestionBank.description
FROM         QuestionBank INNER JOIN
                      Question ON QuestionBank.questionid = Question.questionid
WHERE     (QuestionBank.description = @description)

SELECT     @type = Question.typeOfQuestion
FROM         QuestionBank INNER JOIN
                      Question ON QuestionBank.questionid = Question.questionid
WHERE     (QuestionBank.description = @description)

if @type=1
begin
SELECT     OptionQuestion.option1, OptionQuestion.option2, OptionQuestion.option3, OptionQuestion.option4
FROM         OptionQuestion INNER JOIN
                      Question ON OptionQuestion.questionid = Question.questionid
end
GO
```

How can i store the records n in what way???

Comment: Can you please clarify? What do you want to store? Store in the sense of in a variable(s) or in a table?  Do you want to return multiple result sets or join multiple result sets and then return them. It would help if you would describe your goal more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Using `IDataReader` / `ExecuteReader`, you should be able to use:

```
    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        do
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                /* row */
            }
        } while (reader.NextResult()); /* grid */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your stored procedure with the DataSetAdapter.Fill() method. It will populate your dataset with all resulting tables. If you use a typed dataset make sure to set up table mappings (populate the DataSetAdapter.TableMappings collection). Details to be found on MSDN

Comment: DataSetCommand.selectCommand accepts parameter as sqlcommand.commandText,sqlConnction

how to pass parameters in that case???

Answer (score 0):

DataSetCommand.selectCommand accepts parameter as sqlcommand.commandText,sqlConnction how to pass parameters in that case???